# Where to use 'use strict'; in revealing prototype pattern

Tags: javascript

I want to use 'use strict'; in revealing prototype pattern. The problem is that should I use it in constructor function or inside the prototype part in my below code

```
var Foo = function () {
    'use strict'; // should I use it here
};

Foo.prototype = (function () {
    'use strict'; // or should I use it here?
    return {};
}());
```

Comment: How about everywhere? `use strict` only applies to the current and child functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your situation, but I think a good rule is to use it at the outermost scope you can.  If you're working on a site (or a Node application) where you control all the code, put `'use strict';` at the top of every module. (With Node you can bypass that altogether by starting the runtime system in strict mode.)

If you have to deal with 3rd-party code that was written in 1997, you have to keep strict mode localized, but you can still cover your code with module-like anonymous function wrappers inside which everything is strict.

Note that `'use strict';` applies to its scope *and all nested scopes*.  Thus:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  // hundreds and hundreds of functions etc.

})();
```

In that code, *everything* inside the outer anonymous function will be interpreted in strict mode.

Comment: I my case I want to use it only for this module.

Comment: @2619 well if you don't want it global, and you are not wrapping your whole module in an anonymous function wrapper, then you should put it in *both* places.